# Высота блока родителя относительно дочернего элемента

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток, коллеги!
Проблема наверняка до жути элементарная в решении, но скилл не позволяет определить ответа на вопрос.
Задал элементу внутренний отступ, элемент подрос и залез на соседние блоки. Выходит так, что размер блока родителя оставил высоту относительно текстовому содержимому не учитывая его отступы.

[image: Скрин проблемного элемента относительно родителя]
Задачу можно решить присваиванием родителю свойство display.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в индивидуальном формате решение данной проблемы не подходит, т.к придётся добавлять дополнительные контейнеры перед данным элементом и ему подобных.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите найти универсальное решение проблемы, чтобы была возможность помещать ссылку с классом которому определён внутренний отступ в любое место на странице.

Стиль элемента

```
a.button
 background-color: #ffcb0f
 text-transform: uppercase
 color: #fff
 padding: 0.7rem 1.2rem
 border-radius: 8px
 font-weight: bold
```

Ссылки в документе

```
<div class="links"><a class="button" href="#">Know more</a><a class="button" href="#">Know more</a></div>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Добавил в содержание вопроса.

Comment: display: inline-block;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте ссылкам свойство `display: inline-block;`